# Extract .ico icon from sites like Amazon, eBay

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code that parses an html page's header looking for ICO images that declared in the following way:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

for example with the code:

```
image = htmlDoc.querySelector('link[rel="shortcut icon"]');
if (image) {
     imageUrl = image.getAttribute('href');
}
```

*(I don't have cross browser issues, because I have an extension's privileges)*

The problem is whenever I go to such sites like http://www.ebay.com, or http://www.amazon.com, they don't have .ico image in their DOM's header, nevertheless the brand's .ico image is displayed as usual.

My question is:
Do we have some other ways to attach .ico images beside the way mentioned above or how do they do it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon // Originally, the favicon was not explicitly linked or referenced anywhere, browsers just assumed it to be available under the name `favicon.ico` in the root directory of the site.

Comment: `else{ imageUrl = '//' + websiteName + '/favicon.ico'; }`

Answer (score 7):

Most browsers will look for a `favicon.ico` in the root directory if no favicon is specified. [Ebay has such an icon](http://ebay.com/favicon.ico) which is why the favicon is showing even though it's not declared in code.

You may be interested to know that Google has a small API for favicons, so you may not need to implement this yourself.

Simply create an image tag and set the `src` to something such as:

```
http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=amazon.com
```

...and you will get the Amazon favicon.

Answer (score 4):

Favicons can also be put to the websites root and most browsers will try to search for them there.

For example, see http://www.ebay.com/favicon.ico for the eBay icon or http://www.amazon.com/favicon.ico for the Amazon favicon.

Answer (score 2):

According to [W3](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon), there are two methods to add a favicon to a website ;

**Method 1 :**

rel attribute could be used for adding favicon. 
Example : `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/myicon.png">`

**Method 2 :**

Using the predefined path. Some browsers automatically checks for this path and displays the favicon if it is exists.
Predefined path for favicon is `"/favicon.ico"` respect to the server's root folder.

Websites you mentioned that have no link rel tag are using the second method. You can get the favicon by directly querying that predefined URI.